# How to download Qt4.8 on a Mac

Tags: macos, qt, qt4, qt-creator, osx-mavericks

I'm new to Qt and was trying to download Qt version 4.8 from their website. I downloaded the Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Mac (185 MB) and debug libraries (480 MB). After installing both of them I found that Qt Creator was not bundled with the installation.

I downloaded the Qt Creator 3.0.1 for Mac (62 MB) in the same downloads page. If I open Qt Creator now, I am not able to create a New Project and it says "No Kits found".

Its been really frustrating. I would appreciate if anyone could elaborate on how to link all the installations together and start-up a new project in Qt 4.8.

**Edit:**

I am trying to use VTK 6 library and it seems that Qt 5 does not support VTK 6. Hence I had to go for Qt4.8. This is the screen I'm getting when I try to add the Qt version.

[image: I'm not able to select qmake.]

Why am I not able to select qmake executable in the above image. I'm trying to select the qmake from /usr/bin/

Comment: Seems a known bug https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-6222 . I cannot test now for I have no    OS X at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add kits in the options, follow the instruction here:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-targets.html

It seems to be a known bug on OS X, see: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-6222 for some workarounds.

Comment: Ya, I tried to do it, but then my machine is not recognizing a Qt version. How do I do it manually?

Comment: You can find the path of your qt 4.8 installation and add qt version first, see http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-project-qmake.html. Then add kits.

Comment: If you don' t mind using qt 5.2, you can just use the online installer at the same download page, and select qt libs and qtcreator there. It would be well integrated.